# Laravel - How to get value through pivot table with selected

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I have 3 table

```
users: id, full_name

user_projects, user_id, project_id // Pivot table

projects: id, name
```

In users table, I got **10 user**

In project A, I want 3 user to do project A.

Then I create function to store project A

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    try {
        $project = new Project();
        $attribute = array_only($data, $project->getFillable());
        $project = $project->store($attribute);
        if (!empty($project)) {
            $project->user()->attach($request->user_id); // Insert to pivot table
        }
        return redirect()->route('project.index')->with('flashSuccess', 'Create is successful!.');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Log::error($ex);
        return view('errors.404');
    }
}
```

**Then when I press Edit, I want to show all 10 user in users table and 3 user who join in project A (user in pivot table) with selected already.**

I can get all user who join in project A in view selected but I can show all another users in users table.

Here is my views:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <select id="dates-field2" name="user_id[]" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
       @foreach($project->user as $user)
          <option selected="selected" value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->full_name}}</option>
       @endforeach

    </select>
 </div>
```

Here is my Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_projects');
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Just select all users with a separate query.

Comment: Can you give me more detail ?

Comment: Detail on what? How to query database? Laravel manual is full of it.

Comment: I can get all user who join in project A in view selected but I can show all another users in users table. I don't need query to get this.

Comment: So if you don't need query - then what do you need?

Comment: I want to show all 10 user in users table and 3 user who join in project A (user in pivot table) with selected already. I can display all user with $users = User::all(), and get all user who join in participant with foreach in views.

Comment: Your question is vaguely stated. Title indicates a general functionality and your question body shows the code and what you can do, but **not what you cannot achieve**

Comment: Get all 10 users with a __separate query__. While iterating over them check if this user is engaged in a project.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your user is already in current project 
($project_id is your current project)

```php
<div class="col-md-4">
   <select id="dates-field2" name="user_id[]" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
       @foreach($users as $user)
      <option {{ in_array($project_id, $user->projects->pluck('project_id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->full_name}}</option>
   @endforeach

</select>
```